# GAE Deployment error (Need to deploy my app multiple times to work )

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-storage

Just recently my GAE app stopped working and it cannot connect to cloud storage and a couple of more issues. I am using GAE and Spring Boot Rest Api.

When I deploy the app on the same version multiple times, one of them randomly works. It is just crazy.

Anytime it does not work, I get different errors like:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/jsonwebtoken/io/SerializationException
```

Sometime I get another error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
```

If I deploy the app multiple times using IntelliJ, magically, I do not get any error for one of the deployments. Is something going on with GAE deployment?

I have used the latest version of BOM to prevent any conflicts in my Maven libraries, and still no luck. It just happened out of blue last week without even changing the code. The version that I had online, stopped working today and I had to deploy the app multiple times until one of them worked.

The app works perfectly on my local machine.

Comment: I am suspecting it might be related to this issue and it is not resolved yet. https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/21004

Comment: Nothing yet? no google employee would like to look into this issue? I still need to deploy multiple times until one of them randomly works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who encounters this issue. You need to update your `appengine-api-1.0-sdk` and `google-cloud-storage` to its latest version. I used Maven to update and fix the issues.

I also got multiple errors because of using `io.jsonwebtoken`. The error was:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.security.weakkeyexception: The verification key's size is 48 bits which is not secure enough for the HS256 algorithm
```

I changed my JWT to `auth0` library, and now it works.

Guess why all these things happened? Because Google updated some of the structure of their GAE and if you do not update your app engine you will get an unlimited number of errors with a perpetual cycle of debugging. I hope Google updates people when they make such huge changes that affect many websites.